# Using rsync to retrieve log files

Tags: logging, rsync, system-administration

This question is hard to Google because of the existence of log files generated *by* rsync, which is not what I'm interested in.

What I'd like to do is to use rsync to retrieve log files from a set of servers. Normally when I want a bunch of personal files from my home server to my laptop I'll do something along the lines of:

`rsync --rsh='ssh' -av --progress --partial user@host:source destination`

To say retrieve my vacation videos to show my family. But I would like to now use rsync to retrieve files from servers to a backup location. Since my log files are append only, and frequently written to, is there a way of making rsync smart enough to "follow" the changes rather than revalidating the initial million lines over and over again? If not, is there another application that people use for this? I don't want to use a UDP connection because I want the ability to handle spikes in traffic without losing data and TCP will be too slow, so I'd like to do local files with backups that catch up during periods of inactivity.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem. I wanted to build a log centralization using `rsync`. The problem is, whenever source log files are getting updates, `rsync` transfers **whole** log file to a remote server and deletes the old one. This behavior is so exhaustive, and it made me lose my mind.

Turns out, `rsync` has a `--append` flag which allows `rsync` to update only "the new parts" of a log file. (I tested only on log files)

From man page:

> --append     append data onto shorter files

From [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync%20--append):

> --append
>
> This causes rsync to update a file by appending data onto the end  of the file, which presumes that the  data that already exists on the receiving side is identical  with the start of the file on the sending side.  If a file needs to be transferred and its size on   the  receiver  is  the  same  or longer  than  the  size  on  the  sender,  the  file is skipped. This does not interfere with the updating of a file’s non-content attributes (e.g. permissions, ownership, etc.) when the file does not  need  to  be  transferred, nor does it affect the updating of any non-regular files.  Implies --inplace, but does not conflict with --sparse (since it is always extending a file’s length).

For example

```sh
rsync -avz --append /source/dir /dest/dir
```

It won't re-validate the entire file but it appends the changes only.

Comment: Cool! I haven't had a chance to test it but if it works then great!

Comment: @zachaysan I'm giving some context. We wanted to tail log files of apps for developers so they don't have to log on to the servers directly. Before using this `--append` thing, we were unable to do 'live tailing', we had to close the `tail -f` and run it again. Because rsync deletes the old log file and replaces it with the new one. But now we can do real time log tailing using `--append` of rsync. It works, at least for us.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think it will work for the original question, so thanks for submitting this answer and subsequent clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `logrotate` to split them into smaller files automatically.

Use the `dateext` option in `/etc/logrotate.conf` to make the rotated logs have a consistent filename (i.e. not being renamed after each rotate which is the default functionality but doesn't play well with rysnc).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It's not bad in general, but I was hoping to have a more real time solution in the average case, but I suppose I could break it up into lots of little files.

Comment: @zachaysan What do you mean by `a more real time solution`?

Comment: I'd like a way I can tell rysnc that the beginning of a file will never change. For very large files I don't want the rsync / the operating system to have to read from the beginning of the file just to add that last 0.05% since the last time it checked. For example, if I do `less +G` I can read from the end of a large file extremely quickly. I want rsync to do something similar.

Comment: If you rotate the logs and they're only say 20MB each, is that a problem? Would you notice the difference with it processing the start of such a file as opposed to skipping the first 19MB?

Answer (score 1):

2020 Edit:

I haven't had a chance to validate that `rsync` can now support this, but it appears that someone else mentioned the `--append` flag. I don't want to mislead people if it works, but I'm keeping my original comment here for now.

Original:

After reading through the source code for `rsync`, I've determined that:

1. There is no way to currently set a flag to do this.
2. The way `rsync` works is that is reads the file and calculates a hash for chunks of the file and sends them back to the calling process which matches the hashes. But it does look like it does a full file read each time, even though it doesn't eat up that much bandwidth.

For now I'll use the `logrotate` solution, but I'm leaving this question unanswered because I'm still convinced that there must be a better solution that just works out of the box.